# Can't extract tar file on Linux server

Tags: tar

In 7-zip file manager I created a tar file (with many subdirectories and files inside). I uploaded this file to the Debian server but can't extract:

```
tar -xvfz files.tar
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I also tried tar `-xvf userpics.tar` but then happends just nothing.

Any ideas how to extract this file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a tar file, not a .tar.gz

-z is for gzip

try:

```
tar xvf files.tar
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happends. No error, nothing and the file stays as it is.

Comment: if you type "file files.tar" does it say it's a tar file?

Comment: files.tar: data

Comment: It is not a .tar file then. Try installing p7zip on your server and extracting the file with it. If it was a tar file it should say:
files.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Comment: Strange. What is the reason it's not a tar file? I have done the same many times before (but uploading from a different computer) and it was working just fine.

Comment: I have no idea, maybe it got corrupted on transfer or something simmilar. You can try to transfer it back to your pc, and extracting it there to verify. Or just try taring the files again and sending them again.

Answer (score 1):

`tar xvf files.tar`

As it's not a gzip file, you don't need the `z` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are its not a tar file. Do sudo apt-get install p7zip instead.